# Savon 2 returns nothing in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, soap, wsdl, soapui, savon

Here is my Savon 2

```
   client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL")   
   client.operations   
   response = client.call(:get_info_by_zip, :message => { us_zip: "90210" })
   response.to_hash
```

And response is:

```
   {:get_info_by_zip_response=>{:@xmlns=>"http://www.webserviceX.NET"}}
```

In the SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:GetInfoByZIP>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <web:USZip>90210</web:USZip>
      </web:GetInfoByZIP>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get this response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetInfoByZIPResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetInfoByZIPResult>
            <NewDataSet xmlns="">
               <Table>
                  <CITY>Beverly Hills</CITY>
                  <STATE>CA</STATE>
                  <ZIP>90210</ZIP>
                  <AREA_CODE>310</AREA_CODE>
                  <TIME_ZONE>P</TIME_ZONE>
               </Table>
            </NewDataSet>
         </GetInfoByZIPResult>
      </GetInfoByZIPResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

For the life of me I cant figure it out. Can someone please have a look and let me know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tag within the message seems wrong, instead us_zip you should use "USZip" (in quotes!).

This works for me:

```
#!ruby

require 'savon'
require 'pp'

WSDL_URL = 'http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?wsdl'

client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: WSDL_URL,
  log: true, # set true to switch on logging
  log_level: :debug,
  pretty_print_xml: true
)

zip = ARGV[0] || "98052"

response = client.call(:get_info_by_zip,
                       message: { "USZip" => zip }
                      )

pp response.to_hash
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I get this result when I used this `zip = ARGV[0] || "98052"` and I got this result `{:get_info_by_zip_response=>{:get_info_by_zip_result=>{:new_data_set=>{:@xmlns=>""}}, :@xmlns=>"http://www.webserviceX.NET"}} ` then changed it to `zip = "98052"` and all good now. Thanks again,

Comment: Can you have a look at this question too please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195706/savon-is-returning-no-result-in-rails-4